Rotating WMV videos without reencoding
I'm open to any tool, but I know that ffmpeg can do this for .mp4 files. Also tools like exiftool. I have tried something like this:
ffmpeg -i LEFT_OUTBOARD.wmv -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=180 tmp.wmv

And while it is indeed fast, the video doesn't play rotated in VLC. For the record I've also tried different rotation angles, same result.
Is there any way that I can do this without re-encoding?

Output to .mkv.  i.e. ffmpeg -i LEFT_OUTBOARD.wmv -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 -vf "rotate=180" tmp.mkv

That didn't work either unfortunately, even after removing the extraneous -vf and changing the property to "rotation" VLC still wouldn't play it rotated, though the tag does exist.

Try changing the container to mkv, first:  ffmpeg -i LEFT_OUTBOARD.wmv -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 LEFT_OUTBOARD.mkv  Then, try from mkv to mkv: ffmpeg -i LEFT_OUTBOARD.mkv -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 "rotation=180" tmp.mkv

ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c copy -vf vflip output.mkv  Ever tried flip?  I just ran into it.  I don't know if it would be H or V...  could be worth a shot.

First one doesn't work, and you can't apply filters on a copy, it would re-encode the video. Are you actually trying these commands, or just guessing?

I wasn't trying them, because it's WMV source, which I don't have any of, and each file's usually a unique adventure all of their own.  I just ran into vflip reading and thought of this question.
